# A job for Queue's & Events? CSV file importing and processing

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, csv

I need to add functionality allowing a user to upload a .csv file (+- 300 rows of data), then process the file ... the steps are:

1. The user uploads a .csv file
2. The .csv file is saved to S3
3. Each row in the .csv file is validated and imported into a database table (+- 300 rows)
4. Individual PDF reports are generated and saved to S3 (one for each row of data imported into the database) ie. +- 300 PDF reports generated and saved to S3.
5. Zip all the PDF's into a single file and save to S3
6. The user is notified when the job is done (and can download the zip).
   In your experience, what would be the most efficient way to achieve this if using 3rd party services was out of the question (other than those provided by AWS)

I'm leaning towards ... after the .csv file is uploaded and saved to S3, queue all the other tasks and send the user an email when the job is fully completed? How can I handle all these. User can just upload the csv file and start the process and it should be noticed when the job is done.

Feedback greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems high work task here high is up. You took a charge and want it to be done free. At least you should try and then come with code part if not work. It's too broad.

Comment: @user2486, I am asking the best way to do it. Am not asking to code anyway.

Comment: You basically answered your own question. Job queues is the way to go especially now with Laravel Horizon being available. You can notify the client by email/slack and such/web sockets (Laravel Echo)...

Answer (score 1):

AWS has some great tooling for this type of situation. To start with, you should use S3 bucket triggers with AWS Lambda. It will run code upon the file being uploaded. From there you can either do all of the work or use SQS or other messaging solution to fanout messages to be processed in parallel. Each of these tasks can then be bundled up into a zip file using a separate process if desired and an email, SMS, or push notification can be sent using SNS or SES.

Both AWS SWF and StepFunctions could be used to orchestrate all of the steps and workflow.